failed to run the data pipeline batch in gcs data fusion
i have a csv file which i am loading from a gcs bucket, wrangle it and then connect it to the bigquery table. but the thing is, while i am running the pipeline, spark program end with error: here is the screenshots: .
here is the detailed screenshot of the error:

help me rectify it. the data is loading into bigquery, but, it is failed to load in the bigquery table:  here is the screenshot:
.
here is the property screenshot of bigquery:

i was trying to run the pipeline but it failed to execute as spark didn't run.
i am expecting a solution where spark will run and my data pipeline too.

Can you post the code for the program 'spark-1' and also the details of the error (from the system logs referred to in your screenshot)? Without those there isn't really a way to diagnose this.

Please share raw logs of the pipeline run: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/viewing-logs#download
